# case statement with multiple cases doing same operation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to use a case statement with the control signal being 4 bits. I have multiple cases of those 4 bits doing the same operation, how do I make the code more concise?

For ex:

```
  casez (fbe)  //fbe is defined as logic [3:0] fbe;
   4'b0000: begin
    // operation a
   end
   4'b???1 : begin
    // operation b
   end
```

Operation a and operation b are exactly identical. How do I collapse these 2 into a single case? Something like (fbe == 4'b0000) | (fbe == 4'b???1) into a single case?

Answer (score 15):

You can use commas to separate all case expressions that will perform the operations. The `default` condition cannot be in this list (because it would be redundant).

Example:

```
casez(fbe)
  4'b0000, 4'b???1 : begin /* do same stuff */ end
  4'b??10 : begin /* do other stuff */ end
  default : begin ... end
endcase
```

This is documented in IEEE Verilog and SystemVerilog LRMs with examples. Such as [IEEE1364-1995](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1364-1995.html) § 9.5 *Case statement* and [IEEE1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 12.5 *Case statement*.

Answer (score 8):

In SystemVerilog, you should use the `case (expression) inside` statement. (§12.5.4 Set membership case statement). This lets you use the same kind of lists of expressions that the `inside` operator uses, like a range of values. It also has asymmetrical wildcard matching. This means only Z's in the case item become wildcards, not Z's in the case expression. For example

```
case (fbe) inside
  4'b0000, 4'b0??1: begin end // 0, and 1,3,7
  [9:11]: begin end // 9,10,11
  default: begin end //2,4,6,8,12-15
endcase
```

If `fbe` was `4'bz000` for some reason, the default would be taken. `casez` would have matched `4'b0000`.

Comment: How common is supposed for `case() inside`? Last time I tried (about 2 years ago) most tools (simulator, linter, synthesizer, etc.) didn't support it. When I asked the vendors, their responses basically were: it a known issue, don't to expect it any time soon, use `casez`.

Comment: All simulation tools that support SystemVerilog support this. Synthesis tools are usually a little behind. See http://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2013-SNUG-SV_Synthesizable-SystemVerilog_paper.pdf